# Is there a way to simulate or force a worker switch for azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a nasty lock issue when azure switches the worker and our site goes down...

Is there a way to simulate or force a worker switch for azure webapp so i can debug this issue?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to debug your issue?

Comment: @malonowa no, unfortunately not....

Answer (score -1):

You can only use the available [az appservice plan cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-update) to Update an app service plan